# Lemon zest in large volumes

Tags: equipment, lemon

I need a LOT of organic lemon zest.  Is there a commercial machine that can zest faster and better than a hand held zester?  How do the dried zest companies produce their lemon zest?  There's gotta be an efficient way.

Thank you,
Dina

Comment: Frequently gourmet/high end grocery stores will carry frozen lemon zest, which would save you a lot of time. If you contact a restaurant produce supplier, they might sell you some as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We manufacture cookies and I am going need a lot on a regular basis.  I would like to find out what kind of machine they use so I can purchase one.  Any ideas...  Thanks!!!

Comment: There is a rotating zester that works kind of like a rotating peeler, but if you're zesting the lemons yourself, you'll also have a lot of lemons to deal with. Unless you also have a use for tons of lemon juice, most people find it easier to just get the zest.

Comment: @sourd'oh Big Lemonade Stand!

Comment: Boyajian Pure Lemon Oil can (sometimes) be used as a substitute for lemon zest when what you're after is really just the oil and the aromatics.  It's a good product in my opinion, and a little goes a *long* way.

Comment: What is "a lot"? Have you tried just cutting strips of zest off with a knife (preferrably chisel ground and very sharp) and practice and mincing them (which can give you a more intense zest because you can zero in on the perfect thickness, and less oil is just sprayed off than with grater/zester tools)?

Answer (score 6):

A Google search for "lemon zest machine" and "lemon zest machine commercial" found [this](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/695681046/Hot_sales_customized_lemon_zester_peeler.html) and [this](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/zip-zester-spin-zester-with-zesting-and-garnishing-blades/998ZESTER.html). Both will surely zest *faster* than a hand zester, but probably will not zest 
*better* than a hand zester. The caveat of zesting a lot of fruit in house is that you will then have a lot of peeled fruit that you will also need to find a use for. This frequently works well for places making custards or fruit curds where they will need both the zest and juice. If only the zest is needed, it would be much easier to just get the zest from a produce company or frozen food supplier.